# Instead of using tool tip I need to show chart value in bar chart in kendo UI chart while loading itself

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

[image]I'm creating a kendo ui bar chart. I'm getting proper data, when I hover over the mouse only it will show the data. Instead of that on loading time itself value of each bar should be displayed at the top of that bar.

In below img. Billed Amount and paid Amount is showing when mouse hover over the graph.
I need to show billed amount and paid amount in every bar by default, i mean user should view amount with out mouse hover over the chart

Comment: Can you be more specific ? Try adding screenshots of your chart with annotations...

Comment: I am also confused by this. Do you want to highlight chart B items with a relationship to a selected bar in chart A, when moused over?

Answer (score 1):

Just make the series labels visible

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-series.labels

For example:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
  series: [ {
    labels: {
      visible: true,
    },
    data: [1, 2]
  }]
});
```

You can use the properties of the labels object to change colors, formatting, borders, etc.